# What permissions do i need to send sms?

Tags: android, sms

Can anyone tell me What permissions would i need for sending a text message automatically?
Im not really sure which ones i need i know send and write sms, any others im missing?

Answer (score 2):

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/Manifest.permission.html

I'll let you do the rest of the work